# First automation script - JMeter / WebDriver Sampler / Script Language groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, click

I have a question. I am buildin my first script for JMeter / WebDriver Sampler / Script Language groovy

This 2 fields works great:

```
var txtEmail = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("email"));
txtEmail.sendKeys('example1@hotmail.com');
Thread.sleep(1000);

var txtPassword = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("password-field"));
txtPassword.sendKeys('Passexample1');
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

But i don't know how to automate the click of a button that doesn't have properties "id" and "name". Just have class:

```
<input _ngcontent-dqo-c0="" class=" btn  mt-3 mb-4 text-uppercase btn-primary" type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión">
```

How i can do that?

Automate a button click

Comment: I am trying like this: var btnIniciarSesion = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.class(" btn  mt-3 mb-4 text-uppercase btn-primary"));
btnIniciarSesion.click();       but the windows close and it appears to me this error No signature of method: java.lang.Class.call() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [ btn  mt-3 mb-4 text-uppercase btn-primary]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you could stick to [`value` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)

Something like:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.cssSelector("input[value='Iniciar Sesión'")).click()
```

More information: [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

Also one of the [Top 15 UI Test Automation Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ui-test-automation#design) states:

> **NEVER** use `Thread.sleep()` unless there are specific test requirements

so it worth considering going for [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) instead

Comment: Works greay Dmitri thank you for you help!

Comment: If another button have this properties: <span _ngcontent-tqx-c3="" class=" text-nav d-md-inline-block"> Mis Facturas </span>        how i can automate the click button?

Comment: it may not be a button, but it is an option on the left panel that can be clicked